# How do you see if $(this) has a certain class?

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
$('th a').click(function() {
   var $th = $(this).closest('th');
   $th.toggleClass('selected');
```

How do I say:

```
if ($th('.selected')) {
    alert('selected');
} else {
    alert('not selected');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [`hasClass` method](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
if ($th.hasClass('selected'))  //No dot
```

In general, you're looking for the [`is` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
if ($th.is('.selected'))      //Yes dot
```

Since the `is` method takes a selector, you need to include a `.`.

Answer (score 1):

[hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
if ($th.hasClass('selected')) {
    alert('selected');
} else {
    alert('not selected');
}
```